# Split array on special item and take the items then into different lists

Tags: vb.net

Heyho, I am trying to split an array at a special position and then add the items inbetween into 3 different lists/arrays.

For example I try to do something like that:

```
Test1
Test2
--
Test3
Test4
--
Test5
Test6
```

I want to "split" it at the "--"-items to get the items inbetween.
Then I want to add them to different arrays, like that:

```
Array1:
Test1
Test2

Array2:
Test3
Test4

Array3:
Test5
Test6
```

I have already declared the different arrays and a source array that is filled via **File.ReadAllLines**.

Like that:

```
Dim source As String() = File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
Dim array1 As String() = New String() {}
Dim array2 As String() = New String() {}
Dim array3 As String() = New String() {}
```

So, I have tried to do something with **Array.Copy()**, but I did not manage to do it. 
Anyway, has someone a working way/solution? To add it to a list then is not the problem, because **AddRange** wants an IEnumerable(Of T), so I can easily add this then.

Help is appreciated.
On questions leave a comment and ask. I tried to explain it as good as I could. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be much easier if you use lists to hold the values. So you have a List(Of String) for each section, and have a List of those to contain all the sections. When you encounter a line which is "--", start a new list for a new section.

```
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim src As String = "C:\temp\testtext.txt"
        Dim testSections As New List(Of List(Of String))

        Using rdr As New StreamReader(src)
            Dim thisSection As New List(Of String)

            While Not rdr.EndOfStream
                Dim thisLine = rdr.ReadLine
                If thisLine = "--" Then
                    ' don't add empty sections
                    If thisSection.Count > 0 Then
                        testSections.Add(thisSection)
                        thisSection = New List(Of String)
                    End If
                Else
                    thisSection.Add(thisLine)
                End If
            End While

            ' add on the last one
            If thisSection.Count > 0 Then
                testSections.Add(thisSection)
            End If

        End Using

        ' show the data
        For i As Integer = 0 To testSections.Count - 1
            Console.WriteLine("List " & i.ToString())
            For j As Integer = 0 To testSections(i).Count - 1
                Console.WriteLine(testSections(i)(j))
            Next
            Console.WriteLine()
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Using your sample data, it outputs:

```
List 0
Test1
Test2

List 1
Test3
Test4

List 2
Test5
Test6
```

Of course, you will put the code in a Sub or Function to make it tidy.

Comment: Thanks! Looks very good. If i don't want to output the entries, but save them in exisitng lists, how would I do that?

For example first list of this should give its items in list named "myList1", sencond list of this should give its items in list "myList2" and so on...

Comment: Instead of writing `myList1`, write `myList(0)`, for `myList2` write `myList(1)` and so on. The reason for using 0 instead of 1 is that the index starts at zero, not one. If you use fixed variable names for variable quantities of items, it will make your code messy and difficult to adjust.

Comment: Ah, testSections is the list for all lists generated.
I did not recognize that. Okay, so this is easy now. That an index i zero-based is already part of my knowledge :)

Comment: I hoped the `show the data` part would give you a hint as to what is going on ;)

Comment: Yep :) I just had a brick in front of my head :D
Works perfectly! You earned a thumbs-up and tick! :)
Also thanks for the quick help.

I changed the path and also built in a query if the content is empty to avoid exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the source file can hold a variable number of sections. Therefore I will be using a `List(Of Integer)` to hold the split positions. Also I will add additional virtual split positions before the first and after the last line, this makes it easier to calculate the length of the parts, as they always will be enclosed between two split positions.

Also, since we can have a variable number of sections, we are going to store them in an array of arrays of strings instead of using individual array variables. Further, this has the advantage that we can do the whole copying process in a loop.

```
Dim source As String() = File.ReadAllLines(filePath)

' Create a list that holds split positions.
Dim splitPositions = New List(Of Integer)()

' Add an additional split position at the beginning of the list.
splitPositions.Add(-1)

' Get split positions.
For i As Integer = 0 To source.Length - 1
    If source(i) = "--" Then
        splitPositions.Add(i)
    End If
Next

' Add an additional split position at the end of the list.
splitPositions.Add(source.Length)

' Now all the parts are enclosed between split positions.
' Lets create an array that can hold the parts.
Dim parts = New String(splitPositions.Count - 2)() {}

' Now split.
For i As Integer = 0 To splitPositions.Count - 2
    Dim length As Integer = splitPositions(i + 1) - splitPositions(i) - 1
    parts(i) = New String(length - 1) {}
    Array.Copy(source, splitPositions(i) + 1, parts(i), 0, length)
Next
```

Comment: Thanks! Another good solution. I will have a look at it and keep the structure of this idea. (and the snippet ;) )